# Django - fully override validation for a model field

Tags: django, django-models, django-validation

I have a model that takes a datetime via a form, converts it to unix time, and saves it as a decimal. This is achieved in the `clean` method of the model. The problem is that the `clean` method seems to provide *additional* validation, rather than overriding the basic validation ('is it actually a decimal?', in this case).

I have an `if` statement with two branches. If the model receives no value for this field, it saves the current timestamp. This works correctly. The second branch should, if the field is not none, convert the datetime to a timestamp and save it. The problem is that by the time it reaches the `clean` method, it has already thrown a validation error, because some other validation method has noticed that the input is a datetime, and not a decimal.

The model:

```
class CompanyAnnouncement(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['publish_datetime']
        verbose_name = 'Company Announcement'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Company Announcements'

    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    publish_datetime = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=6, max_digits=18, help_text='Leave blank to publish immediately')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='company_announcements', help_text='', null=True, blank=True)

    def clean(self):
        if self.publish_datetime:
            try:
                self.publish_datetime = self.publish_datetime.timestamp()
            except:
                raise ValidationError(_("Invalid datetime."))
        else:
            self.publish_datetime = dt.now().timestamp()
```

Comment: The basic validation happens in the "clean" functions of the fields.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm overriding `clean` in the code above, and it's throwing an error anyway, so there must be some further validation

Comment: indeed, in the *fields* cleaning (other cleaning functions): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ah, so the above conversion should happen in the form, not in the model?

Comment: yes and no: there happen validations *both* in the `Form` and on the model. The form performs more (including the `clean` on the model, in fact if you `.save()` a model object, no `.clean()` is called). But the *model fields* perform cleaning (and validating) as well.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ok, so I'll do the conversion in the form cleaning, so by the time it reaches the model, it will be a decimal, as the model expects, and will not fail validation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178267/discussion-between-alex-and-willem-van-onsem).